# Show number of columns based on slicer in Power BI?

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

Suppose I have a table with 10 columns.
Is it possible to show columns based on slicer.
Like if I select 3 from slicer then it should show only first 3 columns.
Similarly if I select 5 in slicer then the visual should show only first 5 columns.

Thank you

Comment: Do you required to filter data points in a visual?

Comment: No just want to show columns based on slicer value

Comment: Is it fine? if you have column name in slicers & you can select which column you want to see in your table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide/show column based on their name from slicer then please apply below steps:

1. Go to Transform Data & Select that column which you always want in your table.
2. Do Unpivoted other columns.
3. Use a matrix:
   Drag static column in ROW of matrix.
   Drag Attribute column in Columns of matrix.
   Drag Values column in Values of matrix.
   4.Drag a slicer & put attribute in Slicers.
   Now you can choose column name from slicer which you want to add in your matrix.
   [image: DataSet]
   [image: Filter COlumns]